# Private Web app for a couple, similar to social networks and team communication tools (self-hosted & free/libre)

Tags: open-source, web-apps, collaboration, communication, self-hosted

I’m looking for a Web app which two people can use to plan their free time together and share parts of their lives with each other. A platform for a couple or best friends. For the fun, not for the boring stuff.

I never used [Slack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slack_%28software%29) or [Facebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook), but from what I read about these services, I imagine the Web app to be a combination of them: a mix between a dashboard, a collaboration tool, and a social network (or to be more precise: the stream that seems to be typical for social networks), but only for two people, and without focus on work/development.

#### Required (no room for compromises)

- It must be free/libre software.
- It must run on a GNU/Linux server (I’ll self-host it).
- Everything must be private, only accessible to the two user accounts.

#### Desired features (fine if I can’t have everything)

- Chat / status updates. Similar to the [Stack Exchange chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) or a microblog.
- Create/share posts (text, audio, video, image, file). Both can comment on each post. Inform the other one about new posts/comments. Similar to a blog.
- Create a text document that can be edited by both. Inform the other one about new documents/edits, and color the parts differently. Similar to a wiki, or even similar to [Etherpad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etherpad).
- Manage a shared to-do list. Both can add (and mark as done) entries. Support for categories would be fantastic.
- Add events/dates, maybe with a simple calendar.

#### Presentation (just an idea)

- The content from all of the features listed above should ideally be listed in one big stream. So a chat message could be followed by an image post, which could be followed by a log entry that a text was edited, which could be followed by the reply to the first chat message.
- It should mark entries which are new (i.e., still unread) somehow, so that the users notice when they saw everything.
- Filters could be used to show only image posts, or only to-do entries from the "Watch movies" category. A search could be used to find chat messages, posts, etc.
- A dashboard/sidebar should give easy access to the "stable" content: the to-do list, the events, and the (active) text collaborations.
- An indicator that the other user is currently online would be great. If offline, it should ideally show when the other user was last seen.

Comment: i'm also looking for something like this :-) But currently i've bought a synology nas and you can install anything from mediawiki to photo sharing to a torrent downloader to chat and other tools, on your own private network attached storage. we also stream our movies (that are transcoded on the fly) to our mobile phones @work. buying the nas fixed all major issues : from backup to a private cloud solution + hosting.

Comment: you can try out the live demo here : https://www.synology.com/en-global/dsm/live_demo

Answer (score 2):

You can try **[Sandstorm](https://sandstorm.io/)**:

### Required (no room for compromises)

- It must be free/libre software. - ✓
- It must run on a GNU/Linux server (I’ll self-host it). - ✓ (only 64 bit)
- Everything must be private, only accessible to the two user accounts. - ✓

### Desired features (fine if I can’t have everything)

- Chat / status updates. Similar to the Stack Exchange chat or a microblog. - ✓ [Rocket.Chat](https://apps.sandstorm.io/app/vfnwptfn02ty21w715snyyczw0nqxkv3jvawcah10c6z7hj1hnu0) or [Let's Chat](https://apps.sandstorm.io/app/qkgkaxfqhgsff8zgx2f4nf1a8xvmpte6wa19egmfkk06mzt7e8dh)
- Create/share posts (text, audio, video, image, file). Both can comment on each post. Inform the other one about new posts/comments. Similar to a blog. - ✓ [Ghost](https://apps.sandstorm.io/app/mkqyz71cc96e8gmq2h4dhnfm56k90t2055muv33h2ptw1q6h8n4h)
- Create a text document that can be edited by both. Inform the other one about new documents/edits, and color the parts differently. Similar to a wiki, or even similar to Etherpad. - ✓ [Etherpad](https://apps.sandstorm.io/app/h37dm17aa89yrd8zuqpdn36p6zntumtv08fjpu8a8zrte7q1cn60) or [MediaWiki](https://apps.sandstorm.io/app/y88wavuqwz0p3tjcqtdt8egauq9hpnzr1s9efq1d63rwtj1w0ech) or [DokuWiki](https://apps.sandstorm.io/app/nx3dqcmz2sjjz939vkg4847vvxrzqsatqfjrt3ea50z3jac5kv7h)
- Manage a shared to-do list. Both can add (and mark as done) entries. Support for categories would be fantastic. - ✓ [WeKan](https://apps.sandstorm.io/app/m86q05rdvj14yvn78ghaxynqz7u2svw6rnttptxx49g1785cdv1h) or [Simple Todos](https://apps.sandstorm.io/app/0dp7n6ehj8r5ttfc0fj0au6gxkuy1nhw2kx70wussfa1mqj8tf80)
- Add events/dates, maybe with a simple calendar. - ✓ [Radicale](https://apps.sandstorm.io/app/8kr4rvyrggvzfvc160htzdt4u5rfvjc2dgdn27n5pt66mxa40m1h)

Comment: You missed wordpress

Answer (score 0):

I would consider [WordPress](https://wordpress.org/) as an option. It meets all your requirements and all your desired features of,

## Requirements

- Being free/libre software ✓ - [open source](https://wordpress.org/about/license/)
- Self-hosted on GNU/Linux server ✓ - written in PHP and uses MySQL, which can be setup on Linux servers
- Ability to restrict everything to unwelcome visitors ✓ - using this plugin would be the easiest way, [wp-require-login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-require-login/), simply create two accounts for your friend and yourself

## Desired features

- Chat / status updates ✓ - using any chat plugin, I would recommend [WpChats](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpchats-lite-private-messaging/screenshots/)
- Create/share posts (text, audio, video, image, file) ✓ - This is built into WordPress itself, you can comment on any post
- Create a text document that can be edited by both. ✓ - you could do this with editing posts, WordPress has a built in revisions function that shows what is different between each one using color-coded text. You could also comment about each revision as well.
- Manage a shared to-do list. ✓ - Can be done using a plugin called [Cleverness To-Do List](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cleverness-to-do-list/). It can create shared and private to do lists with category support
- Add events/dates, maybe with a simple calendar ✓ - Can be done using a calendar plugin, I would recommend the plugin [The Events Calendar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/the-events-calendar/)

WordPress is a very powerful system, any other functionality you may need will most likely be able to be accomplished through plugins.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ready to program a little and play around with javascript, there is a meteor  which has an app called [rocket.chat](https://rocket.chat/)

Due to meteor structure, you could implement those by checking if there are any node libs who would give you the other features you would need.

https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=calendar

but again only if you are really looking forward to the program else I would go with an easier way.

Bests